# Simple way of 3d perception

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, cameras, stereo-vision, lidar

I wonder is there any **simple (can be computed in microcontroller level)** option which is suitable for **3d object perception** (depth, position, pose or coordinate estimation) of flying robots except *LIDAR, stereovision, omnidirectional camera, laser scanner* or any other machine vision based techniques

Comment: You could use SONAR or RADAR technologies but the processing power required for any acceptable resolution is prohibitive, there's a reason the technologies you've excluded are most commonly used - they're the cheapest/easiest to implement.

Comment: Thanks. Excluded techniques have good results but if we want to make swarm robot applications this methods brings software and hardware costs. I just wonder is there any cheap alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer is probably going to be an ultrasonic sensor on a servo, you can get them in a huge range of values, from very close to very far range depending on your application, and varying beam widths depending on your accuracy needs. If you need more than 255 steps you could go with a motor and a encoder but that will be slightly more complex.